# how can i align the addon boxes bootstrap - html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem here is that my "OCD" is killing me:

https://jsfiddle.net/3esrpdLt/1/

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
    <td class="quoteprice">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Subtotal: &nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon currency">$</div>
            <input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['subTotal']) ? $invoice['data']['subTotal']: ''; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="data[subTotal]" id="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="quoteprice">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>ITBIS: &nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon currency">$</div>
            <input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['subTotal']) ? $invoice['data']['subTotal']: ''; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="data[subTotal]" id="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="quoteprice">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Descuento: &nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon currency">%</div>
            <input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['subTotal']) ? $invoice['data']['subTotal']: ''; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="data[subTotal]" id="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="quoteprice">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Total: &nbsp;</label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon currency">$</div>
            <input value="<?php echo isset($invoice['data']['subTotal']) ? $invoice['data']['subTotal']: ''; ?>" type="number" class="form-control" name="data[subTotal]" id="subTotal" placeholder="Subtotal" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see on jsfiddle the problem is that when i use the '%' icon it gets a little bigger than the rest, is there a way that i could prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS if you want to make them all larger:

```
.input-group-addon {
    min-width: 40px;
}
```

or, if you want the `%` trimmed down, use:

```
.input-group-addon {
    max-width: 33px;
}
```

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3esrpdLt/2/) what you want?